# What is the difference between "uno A uno" and "uno POR uno?"

Tags: español-neutral

Is there any difference in the phrases "uno a uno" and "uno por uno?"

If not, are there other situations where "a" and "por" are interchangeable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b6hEWeB%7Cb6iKApr), the only difference is the degree to which one considers the elements separate (I've clipped irrelevant entries)

> **uno<sup>1</sup>, na**
>   **uno, na a uno, na.** **1.** *loc. adv.* U. para explicar la separación o distinción por orden de personas y cosas.
>   **uno, na por uno, na.** **1.** *loc. adv.* **uno, na a uno, na** U. para expresar mayor separación o distinción.

You can also use *de uno/a en uno/a* with the same meaning as *uno/a a uno/a* (it is defined without any notes distinguishing it). If you specifically use *una por una* it can also mean "en todo caso, en realidad, efectivamente" although that usage is old fashioned. In all cases, we may presume the meaning to be understood and likely used pan-hispanicly as  the entries lack regional tags.

From Google N-Grams we [can see](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uno%20por%20uno%2Buna%20por%20una%2C%20uno%20a%20uno%2Buna%20a%20una%2C%20de%20uno%20en%20uno%2Bde%20una%20en%20una&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28uno%20por%20uno%20%2B%20una%20por%20una%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28uno%20a%20uno%20%2B%20una%20a%20una%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28de%20uno%20en%20uno%20%2B%20de%20una%20en%20una%29%3B%2Cc0) that the one using *a* surged in usage about a century ago, but using *por* is still used about 35-40% of the time. Using *de/en* is pretty consistent over time, although only about 5-10% of instances.

Basically, we can say that **uno/a a uno/a** is the most common, but that there should be no problem using **uno/a por uno/a**.

Comment: I did not know that you could group results in Ngram using the plus (+) sign!

Comment: @CarlosAlejo you can also use parentheses, minus, and division.  So if you want to find the proportion of use between a and b, you can use *a/(a+b),b/(a+b)*.  Doing it for more than two can be a bit trick, since you run out of space (max query length is 256), but here's with just the masculine forms: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uno+por+uno%2F(uno+por+uno%2Buno+a+uno%2Bde+uno+en+uno)%2Cuno+a+uno%2F(uno+por+uno%2Buno+a+uno%2Bde+uno+en+uno)%2Cde+uno+en+uno%2F(uno+por+uno%2Buno+a+uno%2Bde+uno+en+uno)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=